# Почему не работает условие при нажатии на конкретную кнопку?

Tags: javascript

Набросал свой код - https://jsfiddle.net/djkcsvL2/

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не смотря на условие `keyPress === "Enter"` форма появляется при нажатии на любую кнопку и как это можно исправить.

Заранее спасибо

```js
popupForm = document.querySelector('.popup-form-section');

  const openPopupForm = event =>{
    const target = event.target;
    const keyPress = event.key;
    if (keyPress === "Enter" || openPopupForm) {
      popupForm.style.display = 'block';
    }
    popupForm.addEventListener('click', closePopupForm);
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", openPopupForm);
  };
  
  function closePopupForm(){
  console.log("Закрыть");
  };

document.addEventListener("keydown", openPopupForm);
```

```html
<div class="popup-form-section">
  
</div>

<style>
.popup-form-section{
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Для того, чтобы вам помогли, перенесите код сюда и оформите в сниппет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну потому-что у вас `if(keyPress === "Enter" || openPopupForm)`, `Enter` или `openPopupForm`, а 
`openPopupForm` он всегда, когда вы жмете на любую клавишу(срабатывает `keydown`)

```js
popupForm = document.querySelector('.popup-form-section');

  const openPopupForm = event =>{
    if (event.key == "Enter") {
      popupForm.style.display = 'block';
    }
    popupForm.addEventListener('click', closePopupForm);
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", openPopupForm);
  };
  


document.addEventListener("keydown", openPopupForm);
```

```css
.popup-form-section{
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup-form-section">
  
</div>
```

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно исправить?

Comment: @ИванИванович убрать || openPopupForm из условия

Comment: но если я его уберу, то функция перестанет работать при вызове из другого функции

Comment: @ИванИванович не понимаю о чем вы,как функция может перестать работать из-за этого условия, но дело было именно в этом